# Long strings within variables in jade

Tags: node.js, string, express, pug

I am writing a web application that supports multiple languages. What I am doing is passing strings to a translator class and it will perform the translation. Now I need to add some long text in my templates and I would like to have it on multiple lines for readability.

```
- var longText = 'Some really long text ... '; 
// ... 
p #{i18n.tr(longText)}
```

I would like to do something like

```
- var longText = 'Some text ' + 
-                'some other text'
// ... 
p #{i18n.tr(longText)}
```

Unfortunatly jade does not like that.

Is it possible to have strings on multiple lines in jade?

Comment: can you say why Jade does not like what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this forum, it is undocumented but ending a line in a backslash allows a string to continue onto the next line.

https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1447

Comment: That works just fine, thanks. Weird fact is that if I create the variable with the minus sign it does not work but if I inline the string in the method call works. Anyway problem solved

Comment: Sure, I will do it as soon as stack overflow allows me :)